# PHP why pi() and M_PI

Tags: php, pi

Okay so I misread initially, one is a function and one is a constant. But other than a syntax choice between, say `pi($x)` and `$x * M_PI` there's no mathematical difference between the results of these two options?

Comment: One is a function `pi()` and the other is a CONSTANT `M_PI` [The Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pi.php) There is no `m_pi()` function

Comment: `m_pi()` there is no function in PHP like that instead there is a constant `M_PI`

Comment: Thanks, I had misread that part. Question edited accordingly

Answer (score 3):

The pi() function returns the value of PI. 
Return value:   3.1415926535898
Return type:    Float

The constant M_PI is identical to pi() and is faster than pi().

You can check Other built-in constants identical to M_PI here:
http://www.hackingwithphp.com/4/6/6/mathematical-constants